# Running a command for every new window in tmux

Tags: tmux

I wrote [this thing](https://github.com/mqsoh/tenper) and I'd like to source a Python virtualenv activate script whenever a new window is created in a running session.

Is it possible? The default-command option is related to the shell, not an additional command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am making the following assumptions:

1. You are using `bash`
2. Your `.bashrc` file is source for each new window that starts a shell
3. You only want to start your virtualenv in a window that runs a shell

Add the code you want to run to your `.bashrc`:

```
if [[ $TMUX ]]; then
    # code here
fi
```

This code will only run for new shells which are in an existing `tmux` session.

Comment: This will work perfectly if I provide a tmux environment variable with a session-specific path to an activate script. Thank you, chepner.